# Magento Music Shop - featured artist, producer, publisher tag

Tags: attributes, extensions, tags

I need some help about tagging.

Is (and how) Magento able to make *named tag* (artist, producer, label) and create cms like page to these tags with product list?

For example:
Product: Depeche Mode - Exciter (CD)
Artist: *Depeche Mode*
Label: *Mute Records*

The *Depeche Mode* tag link to all DM album, *Mute Records* link to all products at Mute Records. The linked page should have a custom text (cms) and the related product grid.

Is there any bulit-in hack, or any extension, or I should make my own?

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best approach here is to use Categories as Artists, Products as CDs tied to an Artist (Category) and a [custom product attribute filterable](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/modules_reference/english/mage_adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute/index) for Label. With this approach you do not need to code anything.

Comment: Yes, but it is a big hack, and the number of Artists is not a small list. And what about various artists? So, I really need a nice solution. After music cds, the next problem is dvd (actor, director, etc).